# How can I call $().dropdown function each time a component is loaded in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

During the coding of my react app I decided to use semantic UI for the design of this app. So I implemented it on my index.html file. Personally, I prefer the use of classes instead of the components of React Semantic UI. I need to use the dropdown function, so I added the next code:

```
<script language='javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
  });
</script>
```

Everything is fine, the dropdown is activated when the page is first loaded. But when I decide to use react-router and load a new component with a dropdown inside, this one doesn't open. So my idea is to apply the dropdown function in the functión `componentDidMount()`. But I don't know how to do this.
I have been using load from the `little-loader` library but it doesn't even work.

```
componentDidMount() {
  load('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js', function(err) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
    })
  })
}
```

Here is the error message I've got:

[image]

My idea is not to use the React semantic UI components, due to the lack of animation. Need help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to change

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
});
```

to

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
```

because, even though you're running the first code every time the component mounts, the inner code `$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();` only runs when the whole page has just loaded (and loading a new component/route, of course, doesn't trigger that event).

You may also want to add `console.log(err);` just above `$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();` in case there is a useful error message.

Comment: yeah, that was my first attempt but still getting the same error TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5___default(...)(...).dropdown is not a function
I'm using correctly the little-load library?